# Python, django filter by kwargs or list, inclusive output

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to get get account Ids that will be associated with determined list of ids, currently I filter by one exactly id and I would like to input various Ids so I can get a Wider result.

My code:

```
from typing import List
from project import models

def get_followers_ids(system_id) -> List[int]:
    return list(models.Mapper.objects.filter(system_id__id=system_id
    ).values_list('account__id', flat=True))
```

If I run the code, I get the Ids associated with the main ID, the output will be a list of ids related to the main one (let's say, "with connection to"):

Example use:

```
system_id = 12350
utility_ids = get_followers_ids(system_id)
print(utility_ids)
```

output:

```
 >>> [14338, 14339, 14341, 14343, 14344, 14346, 14347, 14348, 14349, 14350, 14351]
```

But I would like to input more variables avoiding to fell in a for loop, which will be slow  because it will do many requests to the server.

The input I would like to use is a list or similar, it should be able to input various arguments at a time.

And the output should be a list of relations (doing the least number of requests to DB), example

if `id=1` is related to `[3,4,5,6]`

and if `id=2` is related to `[5,6,7,8]`

The output should be `[3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups), in your case use ["In"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup

so:

```
# system_ids is now a list
def get_followers_ids(system_ids) -> List[int]:
    # here add in the end in filter field the "__in"
    return list(models.Mapper.objects.filter(system_id__id__in=system_ids
    ).values_list('account__id', flat=True))

system_ids = [12350, 666]
utility_ids = get_followers_ids(system_ids)
print(utility_ids)
```